# JSON object Array in Spring boot as key value pair using jackson setting

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

We are using spring boot and our response object is as follows :

```
public class ResponseObj<T> implements Serializable {

    private int status;
    private String message;

     protected List<T> objectList;

// with its respective getter/setters
}
```

Now, when for customer object list, I am getting output as

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "message": "Customers fetched successfully",
  "objectList": [
    [
      9,
      "customer1"
    ]
  ]
}
```

How can i get following output of object with key/value pair by any jackson property or spring boot setting?

```
{
      "status": 200,
      "message": "Customers fetched successfully",
      "objectList": [
        {
          "id" : 9,
          "name":"customer1"
        }
      ]
    }
```

T can be any object

Comment: What is T in your case? It should represent your inner Object of the List with the fields 'id' and 'name'